# How to make Isapi Rewrite rules case-sensitive?

Tags: mod-rewrite, isapi-rewrite

I want to direct my users based on a case-sensitive url:

```
www.mysite.com/a ==> page 1
www.mysite.com/A ==> page 2
```

I'm using the ISAPI rewrite with the following rule:

```
RewriteRule ^([0-9a-zA-Z] {1,7}) $/redirect/?K=$1 [L]
```

Apparently this rule is not case-sensitive, since it redirects to the same page. What's is wrong?

=====UPDATE=====

I solved in part this problem by adding a binary query (case-sensitive) in my MySql statement. But in chrome this problem  still occurs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see 2 problems:

1) space between [] and {}

2) your regular expression is non-case sensitive

for lowercase expression you need RewriteRule ^([0-9a-z]{1,7}) $/redirect/?K=$1 [L]
and for upper-case RewriteRule ^([0-9A-Z]{1,7}) $/redirect/?K=$1 [L]